# was resource received via http/1 or http/2

Tags: http, http2

How can I distinguish whether resource was served via http/1 or  http/2? The BE  guys implemented it on their side. and what I  can see in  dev tools network tab that a lot of images (80 items) is loaded in parallel. But when I look at  XHR tab they seem to be loaded by smaller portions. like wait for first 6, than go for another. And it seems that before migration to  http/2 it was the same. I cant see any headers indicatin which version of protocol was used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view that in Chrome using the 'Network' tab in 'Developer Tools', in the 'Protocol' column. If it isn't present, right click on one of the headers ('Status' for example), and select 'Protocol'.

In Firefox, in the same 'Developer'/'Network' panel, when you select one of the queries, in addition to the URL and status code, it displays the version:

[image: Firefox Network panel]

Finally, each of these two browsers has a handy status indicator extension:

- Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/spdy-indicator/
- Chrome: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http2-and-spdy-indicator/mpbpobfflnpcgagjijhmgnchggcjblin?hl=en

Comment: Didn't manage to see the header in Chrome. But it works with FF and solves the problem

Comment: In case anyone like me can't find the protocol column In Chrome on Network tab right click on some column heder and voi la https://s30.postimg.org/yhgfg7cw1/protocol.png